# Do the primal and dual have the same number of basic variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

For the primal problem with constraints $Ax\leq b$ and the dual problem with constraints $A^Ty\geq c$. Since $rank(A) = rank(A^T)$, does this mean that the primal and dual will always have the same number of basic variables?

Comment: The number of basics is equal to the number of rows (constraints).

Comment: Your question does not answer the question that I asked, and has only further confused me. Unfortunately, your comment has not been very helpful. Could you submit a proof?

Comment: In any LP with $n$ columns and $m$ rows, there will be $m$ basics. The primal and the dual are just different LPs.

Comment: And also, my understanding is that with no redundant constraints in the primal $Ax\leq b$, we will have $rank(A)=m\leq n$ and so of course, the number of basic variables in the primal will be equal to the number of rows, $m$

Comment: Suppose we have a matrix $A$ that is $m\times n$ and $n\geq m$. Then assuming no redundant constraints, there are $m$ basic variables. The dual is defined $A^Ty\geq c$ and has $n$ rows but $rank(A^T)=m$. So we can only construct an $m\times m$ basis matrix for the dual. Thus the dual must have $m$ basic variables. Am I missing something? How can the dual have $n$ basic variables in this case, as you say? As the basis matrix must be invertible, wouldn't this necessitate an $n\times n$ basis matrix?

Comment: Any LP has $n>m$ (after adding slacks). Any LP with $m$ rows has $m$ basics.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion here stems from the fact that you must first convert the primal and dual forms to one with equality constraints (because this is required when talking about basic feasible solutions.)

Suppose we are dealing with a maximization primal.

The inequality constraint $Ax \leq b$ can be projected into a higher space by adding slack variables $u$ to get an equality constraint, $$Ax + u = b.$$ Note that $x \geq 0, u \geq 0$. Thus the actual matrix we're looking at is $[A I]$, of dimension $m \times (m + n)$. The rank of this 'primal' matrix is the rank of $A$, so $m$. So, the primal has $m$ basic variables.

The dual of this has the feasible region $A^T y \geq c$ where $y \geq 0$.  However, we need to convert this to an equality constraint too! Add slack variables $s$ to get $$ A^T y - s = c $$ where $y \geq 0, s \geq 0$. 
Note that the matrix we're dealing with in the dual is now $[A^T -I]$, of dimension $n \times (m + n)$. This is not the transpose (or the negative of the transpose, even if $-I$ were $I$.) of the 'primal' matrix, because the dimensions don't match! You can see that the rank of this matrix is $n$, because of the rows of the identity matrix. So, the dual has $n$ basic variables.

Thus, if $m \neq n$, the dual and primal have a different number of basic variables.